# Identifying lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I have, for example 4 lists

```
list1 = [orange, banana, banana]
list2 = [orange, orange, orange]
list3 = [banana, orange, orange]
list4 = [banana, banana, orange]
```

and my main list is, for example

```
MainList = [orange, banana, banana]
```

is there a way to match, In this example MainList and List1 cause they are same?
instead of doing

```
If Main list == list1:
 elif.....etc.
```

I tried it with manually checking every list with stacking if statements, but there must be a better way.

Comment: whats the downside of `If Mainlist == list1:`?

Answer (score 2):

Any time you are naming variables things like `list1`, `list2` it's an indication that those things should be in a list of their own. If you do that, you can check for `MainList` in one line:

```
fruitlists = [
    ["orange", "banana", "banana"],
    ["orange", "orange", "orange"],
    ["banana", "orange", "orange"],
    ["banana", "banana", "orange"]
]

MainList = ["orange", "banana", "banana"]    
MainList in fruitlists
# True

OtherList = ["banana", "banana", "banana"]
OtherList in fruitlists
# False

fruitlists.index(["banana", "banana", "orange"])
# 3
# ...etc.
```

Now instead of `list1`, `list2` you would use `fruitlists[0]`, `fruitlists[1]`, etc. This will be much more maintainable and easier to code than a whole bunch of similarly-named variables.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is very easy:

```
list1 = ["orange", "banana", "banana"]
MainList = ["orange", "banana", "banana"]
print(list1 == MainList)
```

Output: `True`

Answer (score 0):

Put every lists in a single list and loop it
example:

```
total_list = [[orange, banana, banana],[orange, orange, orange],[banana, orange, orange]]

for i in total_list:
   if mainlist == i
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes one possible option is adding all your lists to a list. Then you loop thrue the list of lists until its the same as Mainlist.

Your reselt will give the index off the the mainlist in the list of lists.

```py
list = [["orange", "banana", "banana"],
        ["orange", "orange", "orange"],
        ["banana", "orange", "orange"],
        ["banana", "banana", "orange"]]

MainList = ["orange", "banana", "banana"]


for i in list:
    if i == MainList:
        print(f'index{list.index(i)}')
```

Expected awnser is

```py
index 0
```

Comment: You shouldn’t create a variable using type names like `list` since it’ll reassign the type name.

Comment: The problem with doing that is greatly overstated. Unless you plan on *calling* `list` explicitly in that scope, it's a non-issue.

Comment: @chepner I agree it usually isn’t an issue, but it should still be pointed out. There isn’t really a situation you *would* want this. And within the context of this question it doesn’t add value and could teach poor fundamentals to someone looking to learn.